# Is $E(X_{t+1}\mid\sigma(X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_0))$ is linear or not?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\sigma(X_t,X_{t-1},...,X_0)$ be the sigma algebra generated by the variables $X_i$.

Is $E(X_{t+1}\mid\sigma(X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_0))$ always linear on $X_t,X_{t-1}, \ldots ,X_0$?

Is $E(X_{t+1}\mid\sigma(X_t^2,X_{t-1}^2,\ldots,X_0^2))$ always non-linear on $X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_0$?

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: Is there a way to know when $E(X_{t+1}\mid\sigma(X_t,X_{t-1},\ldots,X_0))$ will be linear on $X_t,X_{t-1}, \ldots ,X_0$? Just when $X_{t+1}$ is a linear function of the previous $X$'s or are there more possibilities?

Comment: No. And no. Which concrete examples did you check?

Comment: @Did I must say I didn't... Which examples do you have in mind? I just read a definition of $E(X|\sigma(Y)$ as the projection of $X$ onto the linear subspace of $\sigma(Y)$ measurable and square integrable variables. So, I just wondered, if being a projection, it would always be a linear in the variables generating the sigma algebra

Comment: It is linear with respect to $X$. No reason to imagine it would be linear with respect to $Y$, note for example that $E(X\mid Y^3)=E(X\mid Y)$, *always*.

Comment: ((Why the deliberate duplicate (not to mention the post on CV...)?))

Comment: @Did I haven't read on prob. theory for some while, and what I knew was very basic. My reasoning was that being $Y$ measurable in $\sigma(Y)$, we could think of $Y$ as being the basis of that linear subspace. 

The reason for the duplicate, was that the other question was framed in a possibly more applied/statistical way, and could put off other users in Math.SE.  the question is CV received little attention, and the users who usually answer, didn't. so it would be very difficult to get an answer there...

Comment: In fact was hoping that you, or one other user (name I've forgotten. sth with Sax? ) would check this question. =D

Comment: @Did I've edited my question, and added one more doubt. I hope you can help me with it. Thanks

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. It is linear if your sequence is jointly Gaussian. To be more specific, it is the projection of $X_{t+1}$ onto the linear span of $\{X_t,\ldots,X_0\}$.

Comment: The conditional expectation is a linear combination in the jointly normal case, as @Calculon explained, and for auto-regressive processes AR$(p)$. Apart from these two cases...

Comment: @Calculon Thanks for your comment. ;)

Comment: @Did thanks for your comment. ;)

Comment: If the sequence $\{X_{t+1},X_t,\ldots,X_0\}$ is jointly uniform, then the condition extectation would be piecewise linear (i.e. non-linear).